# In LaTeX, how can I place text over an imported graphics object?

Tags: image, latex

I have an image in the eps format that I want to include in my document. The image contains only the geometry of the object; it does not contain the necessary text. It has some arrows, and I'd like to add the text in LaTeX so the labels (which include math) look clean.

How can I place an equation at a particular location over an imported figure?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Before downvoting, please note when I asked this question... more than 6 months before tex.stackexchange.com existed

Comment: I didn't downvote. Don't know who did. Seems like a waste of a downvote; it's a good question.

Answer (score 6):

You can use pgfonlayer and tikz. It is a bit complicated, but here is an example I have from a beamer presentation:

```
 \pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
 \pgfdeclarelayer{background}
 \pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
      \path  (1.0,2.0) node (c) {{\color{blue} Some info...}}
         (1.0,1.5) node (b) {{\color{blue}... which is cool!}};
 \end{pgfonlayer}
 \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
   \path      (0,0) node (o) {
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./figures/somefigure.eps}};
 \end{pgfonlayer}
 \end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 6):

Look at the overpic package by Rolf Niepraschk:
http://www.ctan.org/pkg/overpic
It combines includegraphics (graphicx package) and a picture environment.
It is very easy to use!

Answer (score 3):

The [psfrag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PSfrag) package enables you to splice arbitrary LaTeX, including math, in place of text appearing in a .eps file.  I find it indispensable.

Comment: I'll definitely be giving this one a try!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into the textpos package. [See here](http://nxg.me.uk/dist/textpos/)

Comment: Thanks, it looks like that package focuses on absolute positioning, where I'm looking to place text over an image, but not affect the automatic final placement of the image on the output.

Comment: It will also do relative placement.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to just attempt to use `\rput(x,y){text}`, and it worked after some trial and error with the coordinates. This is working for now but I'm still interested if someone has a better way. :)